# Swift UITableView Realm wrong order after delete

Tags: swift, uitableview, sorting, realm

I have a database in Realm which i display in a UITableView which works perfectly. I added a delete functionality which lokks like below.

```
if let item = items?[indexPath.row] {
                do {
                    try realm.write {
                        realm.delete(item)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error deleting item, \(error)")
                }
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
```

Let's say I have some data in the database like 1,2,3,4,5. When I delete the '2' I want it to be like 1,3,4,5 but it is 1,5,3,4. So the last entry respectively the entry which is displayed at the bottom will always replace the deleted data. How can I fix it?

Comment: You should sort the list before displaying it

Comment: There are several options: 1) Sort in code. i.e. load the results you want, sort them, then reload the tableview 2) Let realm do the heavy lifting and sort the data before it's presented to the app. Then reload the tableView. There's not enough info in the question to know what your tableView dataSource is - is it a realm results object or perhaps an array that's populated from realm results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Objects is Realm are stored as unordered if you want them in order then you have to apply below code or store it as a List.

```
let result = realm.objects(ModelClass).sorted("attribute", ascending: true)
```

- ModelClass is the name of your Realm Object Class
- Attribute is
  Object property on the base of which you want them.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: this isn't working if i put the code in viewDidLoad then the tableview is ordered but it is't displayed as it should be

Comment: where you are deleting after that put this ordering logic and then reloadData of tableView.